# Scaling out load balancer devices and a backend network device

Tags: load-balancing

Let's assume we are making a big massive web service for almost unlimited users in the world.

Many articles mention scaling out servers with a load balancer(for example, [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)) and many server machines(or cloud virtual machine instances) like this picture.

[image]

This distributes server machine workload to many servers. However, how can we distribute load balancer workload?

I guess [round-robin DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) or workload-aware DNS server may help. Is that right? (In this case, let's ignore workload problem on DNS server itself.)

[image]

Behind the servers, there is a [DB shard cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)), or partitioned DB instances. Between server instances and DB instances, there is a network device for connected two groups.

[image]

How can we solve workload problem in the network device between DB instances and server instances? If we don't solve it, that network device will be a performance bottleneck or a [SPOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

Comment: *"how to distribute load balancer workload?"* - Once you reach the stage where a single loadbalancer (or fail-over cluster of loadbalancers) is not sufficient you typically won't have all your infra structure in a single location anymore either. You may see anycast + geo  DNS to distribute users over datacenters which are geographically (network latency wise) near to them

Answer (score 2):

#### Not a single device

> How can we solve workload problem in the network device between DB instances and server instances?

This presumes that all the web servers share a network device.  And that all the database shards share a network device.  But that's not a requirement.

Consider a web server with two network cards.  One of them is attached to a public facing network, possibly directly to the load balancer.  The other can be connected to a routing device that can connect to a set of unifying devices.  If there are `m` web servers and `n` DB shards with an average traffic `k` between each pair, then there is `m*n*k` total traffic `T`.  But each router only needs to carry `n*k` or `T/m` traffic.  And each unifier only needs to carry `m*k` or `T/n` traffic.  So adding more servers or shards reduces the traffic demands on each network device (assuming constant total traffic `T`).

We attach network devices to multiple servers because network devices tend to be able to handle a lot more traffic than servers.  It's not a requirement.  You don't need to reduce to a single point of failure (SPOF).

#### The Amazon.com example

Beyond this, there are other places to reduce traffic.  For example, consider how Amazon.com worked circa 2008.  In front, a round robin DNS, which refers clients to one of a set of load balancers for a set of proxy servers.  The proxy servers can examine the request and refer next to an appropriate set of web servers (possibly differentiating based on session, browser instance, or product as well as by page type).  Those web servers would then talk to service servers that would handle information like session, user, order, or product.

The service servers would then talk to the databases.  And they would only talk to their own databases.  If they needed other types of information, they would get it from another service server.  Some service servers could be read only and cache the information.  So subsequent reads would only hit the cache and not the database.  Others would be capable of write operations.

The caching layer can be less robust in some ways than the database layer.  Because the caching layer could be rebuilt from the database layer, it's all right if it gets into a detectably inconsistent state.  This allows caching layers to optimize availability and performance over consistency.  Meanwhile, the database layer can give up write performance in exchange for consistency (and retain availability).

The database layer only faces the write traffic plus a fraction of the read traffic.  For Amazon.com this decreases the database traffic considerably.  This is because write operations, like orders, adding products, and adding inventory, happen much less frequently than read operations like finding and viewing products.  And also, remember that we were splitting the traffic at each level.  So the product information service servers only write to the product information service databases.  And only for a fraction of the products.

#### Partitioning

There are multiple places where partitioning can happen.

- DNS can be [geographic](https://ns1.com/resources/how-geographic-routing-works).  If you are in the US west coast, you may get an IP for the west coast.
- Load balancing can be [sticky](https://www.incapsula.com/load-balancing/sticky-session-persistence-and-cookies.html).  So the load balancer can refer you to the same proxy server each time.
- The proxy server can partition based on

  - Session ID.  The identifier for the current session, based on the cookie or URL parameter.  Single user.  Temporary.
  - Browser instance.  A particular browser running on a particular machine.  May be shared by a small group of users.  Permanent.
  - Type of page.  On Amazon.com, this could be a product page, a discovery (search/browse) page, a cart page, a place an order page, a list of orders previously placed, etc.
  - Page identifier.  This could be a product, order, or search identifier.
- Web servers can be sticky.  You may hit the same one.  So it can cache the service calls that you made previously.
- Different pages call different sets of services.
- Databases can be [sharded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)).  So some of the rows are on one database and some on others.

Identifiers are often partitioned mathematically.  For example, you might partition odd and even.  Or by modulus.  Or by some more complicated method.

#### Why this might not work

Some problems that you may face:

1. What if your service is at the intersection of multiple types?  For example, if your service has to access session and product data.  And it needs a lot of different combinations (potentially all of them).
2. What if your service is comparing multiple instances of the same type?  For example, a game leaderboard may need data from every user.  Which may explain why leaderboards often only show the top hundred or whatever.
3. What if your data doesn't have a natural partitioning?  For example, a user's order might include multiple products from multiple sellers.  Do you partition order items by product, buyer, or seller?  The problem is that different use cases might query by any of those.
4. Perhaps your data does more writes, so caching is less help.  You may want to consider if a database is the right persistent store in that case.

Your actual use case may have more specific issues.  These are general possibilities.  And don't panic.  Other systems overcome these issues.  For example, they may add additional systems that duplicate information.  Which of course adds its own challenges.